# Transfer MSN Live ID

Tags: microsoft, windows-live-messenger, office-365

Microsoft offers a function to change the Live ID (the email that registers the Live ID) to another. I wonder if I changed the Live ID, will my friends' that added me to MSN will update their Friend's List (with my new email)?

Also, I linked my Live ID to XBOX Live. Will my XBOX Live Gold Membership be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything as all your information should be transferred to your new ID.

Taken from the Change Live ID screen

> When you rename your Windows Live ID,
>   your new ID works just like your old
>   one. All of your account information
>   and contacts will automatically
>   transfer to your new ID within 48
>   hours.

If you are concerned about your Gamer Tag this can also be changed manually. Although I would wait at least 48 hours after changing your Live ID before attempting to move this.

[Change the Windows Live ID associated with your gamertag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945419)